# Java - Gui Components do not show up

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have this code to create a simple gui (by hand) and I am trying to display gui components on the frame. However, when I run the program, only the frame shows without showing the components, such as the JTable.

Any idea why ?

```
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*; 
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI extends JFrame {
    public void buildGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hotel TV Scheduler");    
        frame.setVisible(true);

        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel listPanel = new JPanel();
        listPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JTable chOneTable = new JTable();
        JTable chTwoTable = new JTable();
        JTable listTable = new JTable();

        listPanel.add(chOneTable);
        listPanel.add(chTwoTable);
        listPanel.add(listTable);

        contentPane.add(listPanel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should set a `preferredSize()` on the JTables and do a `pack()` afterwards.

**Edit:**

Moved `setVisible(true)` after `pack()`. This is the [order which is used by Sun/Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html).

```
public class GUI extends JFrame {
    public void buildGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hotel TV Scheduler");

        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel listPanel = new JPanel();
        listPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        Dimension d = new Dimension(100, 100);

        JTable chOneTable = new JTable();
        chOneTable.setPreferredSize(d);

        JTable chTwoTable = new JTable();
        chTwoTable.setPreferredSize(d);

        JTable listTable = new JTable();
        listTable.setPreferredSize(d);

        listPanel.add(chOneTable);
        listPanel.add(chTwoTable);
        listPanel.add(listTable);

        contentPane.add(listPanel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know `frame.setVisible(true);`, this must come after `pack()` :-)

Comment: even if you try what the OP has given in the question, even that too works sometimes :-)

Comment: @GagandeepBali  I would say 'must' is too strong a word here.  If someone does not mind the GUI looking amateurish and appearing as a small size before assuming the natural size, and without using the (wonderful) `setLocationByPlatform(true)` then setting a GUI visible before pack **would** work reliably.  Of course, those are good reasons ***not*** to do it that way.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson : Too true, agreed :-)

Answer (score 2):

1. Construct the `JFrame` instance
2. Add the components to the `JFrame` instance
3. Realize the `JFrame` instance (i.e. `setVisible(true)`)

The reason none of the components show up when the `JFrame` instance is shown is because you add components to it after it has been realized. If you want to components to show up, either follow the steps above, or at the end of the `buildGui` method, revalidate/repaint the container.